# Show that $e^{-rt}E\Phi(S_T)=S_0N(d_+)-Ke^{-rT}N_{d_-}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-integrals, density-function

Show that $e^{-rt}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)]=S_0N(d_+)-Ke^{-rT}N_{d_-}$ where

$S_t=S_0e^{(r-\sigma ^2/2)t+\sigma W_t}$ for $t\in[0,T]$ , $W_t\sim \mathbb N(0,t)$ and $N$ is the cumulative density function of the standard normal distribution.

Also:

$$d_\pm=\frac {ln(S_0/K)(r \pm \sigma ^2/2)T}{\sigma\sqrt T}$$ and $\Phi(S_t)=(S_t-K)^+=max(S_t-K,0)$

**What I tried: Let's do it for the 2nd part of the Integral - The K term**

$e^{-rT}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)]=e^{-rT} \int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)\phi(z)dz+ e^{-rt} \int_{-\infty}^K 0$

So I am assuming I only need to find $$e^{-rT} \int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)\phi(z)dz$$
Using $S_t=S_0e^{(r-\sigma ^2/2)t+\sigma W_t}$
Since $W_t=\mu+\sqrt T Z$ where $Z\sim (0,1)$ I can rewrite this as a density function.

$\int_K ^\infty (S_0e^{(r-\sigma ^2/2 t + \sigma (\mu + \sqrt T Z))}-K) \times \phi(z) dz=$

But I'm having trouble from them on. I can't even equate the simple second term together. That is if I take $K$ out.

I should get $\int_K ^\infty -K \phi(z) dz=-KN_{d_-}$

**What Am I doing wrong?**
$\int_K ^\infty -K \phi(z) dz=-K P(Z>K)=-KN$ where $N$ is the cumulative distribution. But why am I missing the $d_-$?

Comment: What do you mean by $e^{-rT}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)]=e^{-T} \int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)+ e^{-rt} \int_{-\infty}^K 0$? It doesn't make sense. Use characteristic functions instead. Use the fact that $\mathbb{E}\mathbb{1}_A=\mathbb{P}(A)$. Let me know if you want a comprehensive answer please.

Comment: @luka5z Sorry, I missed the r. $e^{-rT}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)]=e^{-rT} \int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)+ e^{-rt} \int_{-\infty}^K 0$

Comment: What I meant was that $e^{-rT}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)]=e^{-rT} \int_{-\infty} ^\infty (S_T-K)I_{P>K}=e^{-rT} \int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)$. We are also supposed to use the hint the cdf of N satisfies $N(x)=1-N(-x)$

Comment: Still, it does not make sense. You can't calculate expectation like that.

Comment: @luka5z I need to multiply this by the distribution function of $S_t$ which only depends on $W_t$. So I should have wrote $e^{-rT}\mathbb E[\Phi(S_T)I_{(S_t>K)}]=\int_K ^\infty (S_T-K)\phi(z)dz$ where I can use the fact that $W_t=\mu + \sqrt T \mathbb Z$ and change $\phi(z)$ to $N$ where N is the standard normal distibution

Comment: @luka5z Can you please show me how to do the latter part? That is $\int_K ^\infty -K \phi(z) dz=-K \phi(z)_{d_-}$ where  $\phi(z)=N$ is the cdf of the normal distribution?

Comment: What I get is $\int_K ^\infty -K \phi(z) dz=-K P(Z>K)=-KN$ where $N$ is the cdf as required, but it's not equal to $-KNd_-$

Comment: Figured it out after 3 days.

Comment: See http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/understanding-nd-1-and-how-to-use-the-stock-itself-as-the-numeraire/21486#21486 for derivation.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you, I used the fact that $S_T<K$ iff $Z<d_-$ by changing $S_T$ to a standard normal and taking logs. Anyway, I will look over the linked question in more detail when I have time.